# Django SQLite foreign key mismatch error

Tags: django, sqlite

```
class item_sort_info(models.Model):
    sort = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, null=False)


class items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, primary_key=True)
    inventory = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    sort = models.ForeignKey(item_sort_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class item_info(models.Model):
    serial_num = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    items = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inbound_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class pur_history(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    item = models.OneToOneField(item_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Why am I getting a Django SQLite "foreign key mismatch" error when executing that script?

compiler said

foreign key mismatch - "pur_history" referencing "item_info"

Comment: You don't have `customer_info` model in your code but you are referencing it inside your pur_history model. And please follow some standards during coding. Always use Capitalize name while creating your class. For example it should be `ItemInfo` instead of `item_info`

Comment: The problem is not about `customer_info`...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **"to_field"** argument to field **"item"** in **"pur_history"** class like this:

```
item = models.OneToOneField(item_info, to_field='serial_num', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I hope this works, it worked for me