# django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "Entry_returncylinder" referencing "Entry_cylinderentry"

Tags: django

Getting following error even after I have cleared all migrations.All was working fine until I tried to primary_key to my Cylinderentry model later on I removed but still it displays "django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "Entry_returncylinder" referencing "Entry_cylinderentry" "

when I run py manage.py makemigrations it displays:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to cylinderentry without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).splays following :
```

or when I run py manage.py migrate it displays:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "Entry_returncylinder" referencing "Entry_cylinderentry"
```

here is all models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','availabe'), 
    
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cylinderId


class IssueCylinder(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.OneToOneField('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        
        return self.userName

class ReturnCylinder(models.Model):
    rechoice=[
    ('fill','Fill'),
    ('empty','Empty') 
    ]
    reav=[
        ('Yes','yes'),
        ('No','no')
    ]
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('CylinderEntry',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey('IssueCylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=rechoice)
    returnDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=reav)

    

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            IssueCylinder.objects.get(userName=self.user.userName).delete()
            if self.status=='yes' or self.status=='Yes':
                CylinderEntry.objects.get(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('available'))
            else:
                CylinderEntry.objects.get(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).delete()

            

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cylinder
```

I don't where I m missing. Help!!

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267154/django-sqlite-foreign-key-mismatch-error, i think it might help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but its not working.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that I have been tried to put primary_key to my CylinderEntry model and later on I remove it, this is why this error occurred. To resolve this I just cleared my all old migrations(which I didn't perform in the previous case) and run all the migrations again.

Answer (score 0):

**Missing Primary Key: The CylinderEntry model previously lacked a primary key, which is essential for foreign key relationships.
Add an Explicit Primary Key:

Modify the CylinderEntry model to explicitly include an id field as the primary key:

```
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Add this line
# ... rest of your model fields
```